# Permutation test or two sample t-test in the A/B test setting

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, permutation-test

Assume a website redesign its page and want to assess whether the new design improves the click through rate (CTR) comparing to the old page.

Say we have 1 million traffic and the company randomly split half of the traffic to the old page and the remaining half to the new page.

I believe the conclusion draw from permutation test and two-sample t-test will be the same in this case, as we have large sample. But I want to know if one can still claim one test is "better" in some sense than the other?

As we have large sample, CLT applies, and we should be fine with using two sample t-test. On the other hand, the permutation test almost makes no assumptions (the randomization assignment is ensured in this example). However, the permutation test talks nothing about the super-population that generates this 1 million sample subjects, i.e., permutation test treats these 1 million people as the population. The two-sample t-test does assume that there are two super-populations that generates the half million people who see old page and the half million people who see the new page. But there is no way to statistically justify these two super-populations are indeed the target population of the company. For example, may be the company is target at all people in the world, but somehow the data they run the experiment, i.e., that 1 million people, only contains the people in North American (may be not a good example here, but I think you get my point). So it seems that the permutation test cannot say anything about external validity? i.e., make a generalization of the conclusion from the experiment. But it seems it is also the case for the two-sample t-test, even though conceptually, there are two super-populations under the hood (and we don't know to what degree these two conceptual super-population represent the target population)

Comment: What is your question? What would be the statistical method that you think can be externally valid?